# What is the most efficient way to read the file using java?

Tags: java

I have one of a text files which contains 100 millions of records. i am using very old way to read the file but it took long time and unable to complete because of out of memory issue. I really appreciate if you can recommend best and optimum way to read file using java or using whatever external library.(ultimate solution should be reduced the time consuming) Here is my code as i explained above,

```
BufferedReader reader = null;

    List<String> fileLines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line = "";
    reader = new BufferedReader(new java.io.FileReader(file));
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        fileLines.add(line);
    }
    reader.close();
    return fileLines;
```

Also used another way but result is same.

```
 public static void fileReading(File file, Object executingClass, String methodName, int size) throws IOException {
    try {
        Method method = executingClass.getClass().getMethod(methodName, List.class);

        BufferedReader reader = null;

        List<String> fileLines = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line = "";
        reader = new BufferedReader(new java.io.FileReader(file));
        int track = 0;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            track++;
            fileLines.add(line);

            if (0 == track % size) {
                method.invoke(executingClass, fileLines);
                fileLines.clear();
            }
        }

        if (!fileLines.isEmpty()) {
            method.invoke(executingClass, fileLines);
            fileLines.clear();
        }

        reader.close();


    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to process the records one after the other, without storing all of them in memory.

Comment: You are attempting to read the entire file into memory by adding each of the lines to a list. Java's JVM has a ~1GB limit by default (though you can increase it). Why can't you read each line at a time, do whatever processing you need and then throw it away?

Comment: i have updated my question please see. by using my new method i getting 1000 string list at a time and process it.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by efficient?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you're understanding us. You should be doing something like `method.invoke(executingClass, ONELINE)` 100 million times, not `method.invoke(executingClass, BILLIONLINES)` once.

Comment: i need to reduce memory that it takes to load. and also need to reduce time

Answer (score 1):

You have two alternatives:

1 - Preferably, don't read the whole file and store it in memory. Just read one line (or group of lines representing an entry), process it, and repeat it for all the lines in the file.

2 - If you really really need to store the whole file in memory, try increasing the size of the JVM heap.

Comment: "If you really really need to store the whole file in memory..." then revise your algorithm because no you don't.

Answer (score -1):

Try enlarging memory allocated to the JVM in Java by passing following arguments:

```
-Xms=3000m -Xmx=5000m
```

Where `m` denotes MiB. You can also use `g` for GiB.

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0131.html

Comment: You should only do this if you have to. He probably doesn't have to.

Comment: i dont know dude